# Remove global shortcut in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts

Got an application that installed a global shortcut (ctrl+shift+v) for launching itself. Problem is that this shortcut is frequently used in other applications like Lightroom.

I don't want to remap all other applications using this shortcut, so how do I get rid of this global annoyance?

kind regards,
Ladyhawke

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly you have an application that has set itself to run when you press (ctrl+shift+v) but, as this hotkey is used by other programs, you do not want the hotkey to run your program but instead to do what the other applications may want it to do.

One place where an application run shortcut can get set up is in the shortcut on the Start-menu.

Find the program that is being run by the hotkey under your start menu, right click it and select "Properties".  On the Shortcut tab there is a "Shortcut key" field.  If this is showing the hotkey that you do not want then click the mouse in the field and press either delete or backspace to clear it.

If there was nothing in that field you may need to scout around you desktop for other shortcuts to the application where this hotkey may be set up.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the only way is to change this from within the application; it's the one listening for the event. What is the application?

Comment: Problem is... there's no option to change shortcuts from within the application. Could it be some setting in registry or something like that, I could look for?

Comment: The application is an interface to connect to en engine computer in order to read and set status on various parameters on a car